# Need assistance with a while loop to make the print statement work

Tags: java, while-loop, println

Design and implement an application that determines and prints
the number of even, odd, and zero digits in an int value read from the keyboard.

Example:

```
Enter a number: 100504575
The number: 100504575 has 3 zeros, 1 evens, and 5 odds.
```

so the code is saying to enter a number, then it'll count how many evens odds and zeros, then it will print that number again and say how many evens odds and zeros there are. the counting part works i just can't get the num part to work in this print statement. if i entered the number 1384932 it should print back out: The number: **1384932** has 0 zeros, 3 evens, and 4 odds. **currently** it prints out: The number: **0** has 0 zeros, 3 evens, and 4 odds.

System.out.print("The number: " + **num** + " has " + zero + " zeros, "
        + even + " evens, " + "and " + odd + " odds.");

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int even =0, odd = 0, zero = 0;
        System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
        int num = Scan.nextInt();
        while(num > 0) {
            int digit = num % 10;
            num /= 10;
            if(digit == 0) {
            zero++;
            } else if(digit % 2 == 0) {
                even++;
            } else {
                odd++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The number: " + num + " has " + zero + " zeros, "
                + even + " evens, " + "and " + odd + " odds.");
        Scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the language as a tag

Comment: You loop never exits because `num` is always `> 0` unless you entered `0`. Go with @ChiefTwoPencils answer to change that. But I added a different way to think about it also.

Comment: yes @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: @MichaelPickett, the loop will exit because `num /= 10` will eventually take it to `0`;

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Ah, I missed that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` will be `0` since that's your sentinel value to stop the loop. No problem, just copy the input into another variable that will be used in the `while` loop.

```
int num = Scan.nextInt();
int looper = num;
while (looper > 0) { ... }
```

This way `num` retains the value taken with the `Scanner` and the other is the one altered during the loop. Of course, you'll need to refactor all instances of `num` to be `looper` inside the `while` loop as well. You can do that with a `Replace All` very easily.

Comment: that is what i was missing, thank you for your help! it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code to make use of `String`, so that you can enter in as many characters as you want without having to worry about `int` limitations.

I used a `int[]` with size `3` to count the zeros, `nums[0]`, the odds, `nums[1]`, and the evens. `nums[2]`.

It takes the number entered, trims off any whitespace, and parses the `digit` using `charAt()`. Then it checks.

Let it be known, this assumes that only integers will be entered, no spaces or letters or special chars.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] nums = new int[3];
    System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
    String num = Scan.nextLine();
    num = num.trim();
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
        int digit = Integer.parseInt("" + num.charAt(i));
        if(digit == 0){
            nums[0]++;
        }else if(digit % 2 == 0){
            nums[2]++;
        }else{
            nums[1]++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The number: " + num + " has " + nums[0] + " zeros, "

            + nums[2] + " evens, " + "and " + nums[1] + " odds.");
    Scan.close();
}
```

Comment: how you wrote that in minutes i'll never understand...thank you for your help

Comment: I've done it before. If you want to keep your way of doing it, which works, use @ChiefTwoPencils answer. It addresses your core question, where my answer is just a different way of thinking.